# Advice on using pointers for malloc and free

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

```
    char arr[120];
    for (k = 0; k < 120; ++k) {
        arr[k] = (char *)malloc(1);
    }
    for (k = 0; k < 120; ++k) {
        free(arr[k]);
    }
```

I have the above code. I was wondering why I am getting a Segmentation Fault error when I compile and run the code. Any advice for changes?

I just want to point out that the code above is for a school project.

Comment: There is no need to cast the output of malloc in C. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc#:~:text=If%20you%20use%20malloc%20in,will%20return%20a%20void*%20type.

Comment: Your compiler complained about your code.  Heed your compiler.  It knows a lot more about C than you do.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing `char*` objects into an array that can only store `char` objects. That's undefined behavior. You need:

```
char* arr[120];
```

Comment: I wish modern compilers would default to treating this type of mistake as a fatal error with a meaningful diagnostic message.